# XML code adjustment help required

Tags: xml, feed

Part of the XML feed we are pulling data from into a website that contains price is below:

```
<AskingPrice currency="GBP">12345</AskingPrice>
```

The feed previously though had the below:

```
<AskingPrice>12345</AskingPrice>
```

We previously had in our import settings to pull the value the below:

```
£{AskingPrice[1]}
```

What should our new output in the import feed be?

The below?

```
{AskingPrice currency="GBP"[1]}
```

We don't have a test feed or staging area setup, so have no facilities for testing, so need to get it right first time in this instance. Thanks.

Comment: Import settings in what kind of import process? A clue about those cryptic settings would be nice...

Comment: XML is a data format used by countless applications.  Your application is specific to one of those application, which you've not revealed to us.  You should [edit] your question and add the application name and version that's associated with your "setting".  Thanks.

Comment: It's not an application and holds no relevance. The question is fine as it is, it's a question on how to re-order/restructure the xml code. I've edited the question to make it a little clearer though on the xml feed change.

Comment: _"We previously had in our import settings to pull the value the below: `£{AskingPrice[1]}`"_ -- That "import setting" is not a common, well-known convention or format.  It is obviously understood by some program that is importing the XML.  Unless you reveal what program that is, and where we can see documentation of its "import settings", nobody here can possibly help you.  Adding a bounty will not improve things until you give sufficient information for someone to understand the requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my comment above:   I meant to write: *Your **question** is specific to one of those applications, which you've not revealed to us.*  You've still not identified the application -- that's why nobody has been able to help you yet.  As @JimGarrison has added, a bounty won't help here until you clarify your question by stating the specific *application* of XML you asking about.  This is not an *XML* question as written -- it's an *application* question.

Comment: The "XML code" you reference in the title is probably written in a programming language, and probably using an XML processing framework. It would benefit answerers greatly to know what that language/framework is. It is an application, even if that application is only a small javascript section in a website, or a PHP/.Net page, content management system, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> no facilities for testing

This question isn't really about technical issues; keeping existing setup or switching to your proposed `{AskingPrice currency="GBP"[1]}` should work fine.

This question at its core is asking: "Should I create a small unit test that can answer simple questions?" The answer is: Yes.

There's no need to wait on asking strangers who might devote time to technical answers, when you could just ask the machine, and iterate in minutes rather than days.